# Osmbonuspack - click on bubbles/markers jumps to action

Tags: android, osmdroid

Using Osmbonuspack: In my App, I can show the Markers/Bubbles on a map. Works great.

When clicking on a Bubble/Marker, I would like to do an action, e.g. displaying information in another Frame of the App. So, navigating to another screen of my App.

How can I attach a click handler to the Markers? Depending on the one clicked, I will show the related information.

So, no options menu is needed this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday I saw that the API of the Osmbonuspack has been redesigned. The API is much more intuitive. Great.

In step 0 of tutorial the basics are shown. Just add a setOnClickListener ... and GO!

Comment: What would make this useful for other people who search SO and find this question is a link to the tutorial that explains how to achieve this or a code sample. At a minimum you should accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, I will accept my own answer. But I am only allowed after 2 days.

Comment: Please go to the tutorial step 0: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1. 

Thank you Osmbonuspack team!